# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1) in flutter (in shared_preferences)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a task book, on a flutter, in this project I will use a lot of packages that I have not worked with before (this is not my first question on this project). My goal is to create tasks to add to the status (finished, not finished), and save them locally on the device. I wrote code (with some packages to help me figure it out) that does it all. But the problem arose when downloading questions from the local repository when starting the application. I have an error not to decode the data (in the repository I save a list of our tasks and status). Maybe someone faced such a problem I will be grateful for your help)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:testjob/jsonTodo.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: App(),
  ));
}



class _strikeThrough extends StatelessWidget {
  final String todoText;
  final bool todoCheck;
  _strikeThrough(this.todoText, this.todoCheck) : super();

  Widget _widget() {
    if (todoCheck) {
      return Text(
        todoText,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 22.0,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Text(
        todoText,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _widget();
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AppState createState() {
    return AppState();
  }
}

final ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> _notifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.light);

class AppState extends State<App> {



  bool valText = true;
  var IconsType = Icons.wb_sunny;

  late Color ColorType = Colors.black;

  var textController = TextEditingController();
  var popUpTextController = TextEditingController();

  List<TodoInfo> WidgetList = [];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    popUpTextController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getSP();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> addToSP(List<List<TodoInfo>> tList) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('todoLists', jsonEncode(tList));
  }

  void getSP() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final List<dynamic> jsonData =
    jsonDecode(prefs.getString('todoLists') ?? '');
    if (jsonData.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var data in jsonData) {
        final d = TodoInfo.fromJson(data);
        WidgetList.add(d);
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(
        valueListenable: _notifier,
        builder: (_, mode, __) {
          return MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData.light(),
              darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
              themeMode: mode, // Decides which theme to show, light or dark.
              home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text("Список задач"),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(IconsType, color: ColorType),
                        onPressed: () => {
                          if (_notifier.value == ThemeMode.light)
                            {
                              _notifier.value = ThemeMode.dark,
                              IconsType = Icons.dark_mode,
                              ColorType = Colors.white,
                            }
                          else
                            {
                              _notifier.value = ThemeMode.light,
                              IconsType = Icons.wb_sunny,
                              ColorType = Colors.black,
                            }
                        })
                  ],
//backgroundColor: Colors.orange[500],
                  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                body: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text(
                            "Tasks",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 70.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            iconSize: 70,
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (textController.text
                                  .replaceAll(" ", "")
                                  .isNotEmpty) {
                                WidgetList.insert(0,  TodoInfo(todoText:textController.text.replaceAll(" ", ""), todoCheck: false ));
                                addToSP;
                                setState(() {
                                  valText = true;
                                  textController.clear();
                                });
                              } else {
                                setState(() {
                                  valText = false;
                                });
                              }
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                      child: TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
//color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        ),
                        controller: textController,
                        cursorWidth: 5.0,
                        autocorrect: true,
                        autofocus: true,
//onSubmitted: ,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        child: (valText == false)
                            ? Align(
                            child: Text(("Задача пустая"),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.red)),
                            alignment: Alignment.center)
                            : Align(
                            child: Text(
                              (""),
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.center)),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ReorderableListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          for (final widget in WidgetList)
                            GestureDetector(
                              key: Key(widget.todoText),
                              child: Dismissible(
                                key: Key(widget.todoText),
                                child: CheckboxListTile(
                                  controlAffinity:
                                  ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
//key: ValueKey("Checkboxtile $widget"),
                                  value: widget.todoCheck,
                                  title: _strikeThrough(
                                      widget.todoText, widget.todoCheck),
                                  onChanged: (checkValue) {
//_strikethrough toggle
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (!checkValue!) {
                                        widget.todoCheck = false;
                                      } else {
                                        widget.todoCheck = true;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                background: Container(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                ),
                                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                                movementDuration:
                                const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                onDismissed: (dismissDirection) {
//Delete Todo
                                  WidgetList.remove(widget);
                                },
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
                              newIndex -= 1;
                            }
                            var replaceWiget = WidgetList.removeAt(oldIndex);
                            WidgetList.insert(newIndex, replaceWiget);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        });
  }
}

class TodoInfo {
  String todoText;
  bool todoCheck;

  TodoInfo({
    required this.todoText,
    required this.todoCheck,
  });

  factory TodoInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TodoInfo(todoText: json["todoText"], todoCheck: json["todoCheck"]);
  }

  factory TodoInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) =>
      TodoInfo(
        todoText: map["todoText"] ?? '',
        todoCheck: map["todoCheck"] ?? '',
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {"todoText": todoText, "todoCheck": todoCheck};
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '{todoText: $todoText, todoCheck: $todoCheck}';
}
```

My erorr

```
E/flutter (30831): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter (30831): 
E/flutter (30831): ^
E/flutter (30831): 
E/flutter (30831): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (30831): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:522:7)
E/flutter (30831): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:41:10)
E/flutter (30831): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter (30831): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter (30831): #5      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)
E/flutter (30831): #6      AppState.getSP (package:testjob/main.dart:85:5)
E/flutter (30831): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30831):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change null check value from `''` to `'[]'`.

You set `jsonData` with type **List**. In case `prefs.getString('todoLists')` is **null**, `jsonDecode` will take `''` as parameter, but `''` is **not a valid json** and cause the **FormatException**.

```dart
// final List<dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('todoLists') ?? '');
-> final List<dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('todoLists') ?? '[]');
```

Example: decode strings.
[image]

Updated: copy code in the file and paster to [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/). since I don't have much time, I have omitted the things that are not so important, please add it after the main thread is up and running normally to run. check the dartpad console, you can see everytime you make an update to data, writeTodos was called, place your code in there (dartpad cant use sharedPref library)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  final textController = TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<TodoInfo> data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    readTodos();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void submitAddTodo() {
    if (formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
      final todoString = textController.text;
      if (todoString.isNotEmpty) {
        var todo = TodoInfo(todoText: todoString.trim(), todoCheck: false);
        addTodo(todo);
        textController.clear();
      }
    }
  }

  void removeTodoAt(int index) {
    setState(() {
      data = [...data]..removeAt(index);
      writeTodos();
    });
  }

  void updateTodoAt(int index, TodoInfo todo) {
    setState(() {
      data[index] = todo;
      writeTodos();
    });
  }

  void addTodo(TodoInfo todo) {
    setState(() {
      data = [todo, ...data];
      writeTodos();
    });
  }

  Future<void> writeTodos() async {
    // write data to shared
    print('writeTodos');
  }

  void readTodos() async {
    print('readTodos');
    // read data from your shared insteads hard code `prefsData`
    final prefsData = [
      TodoInfo(todoText: 'todo 1', todoCheck: false),
      TodoInfo(todoText: 'todo 2', todoCheck: false),
    ];
    setState(() => data = prefsData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //...
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    "Tasks",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 70.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    iconSize: 70,
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                    onPressed: submitAddTodo,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
              child: TextFormField(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
                controller: textController,
                autofocus: true,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Список задач';
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: _rTodos())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _rTodos() {
    var wgs = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var todo = data[i];
      wgs.add(GestureDetector(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          value: todo.todoCheck,
          title: Text(todo.todoText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0)),
          onChanged: (checkValue) =>
              updateTodoAt(i, todo..todoCheck = checkValue ?? false),
        ),
      ));
    }
    return ListView(
      children: wgs
    );
  }
}

class TodoInfo {
  String todoText;
  bool todoCheck;

  TodoInfo({required this.todoText, required this.todoCheck});
}
```

Comment: thanks) the error is gone, but my tasks that I created after rebooting the application are not saved)

Comment: @MaksIngenr that is differences question of this post, you may provide more details (console log, etc...)

Comment: when I connect, print and display what I have in the array before opening the application, the array is empty []. So I do not write anything in it. Can you tell me where I may have an error, thank you)

Comment: @MaksIngenr firts you need make sure you saved the string to prefs after `addToSP` complete, cause i dont see any widget that call `addToSP` function.

Comment: and for example used, here is this resource https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/1487/how-to-save-listlistobject-list-to-shared-preferences-flutter. But there is also no example of how to save through the widget

Comment: @MaksIngenr `addToSP` is a function bro, just calling it with a button, etc....

Comment: I added this "+" function to the button but it still didn't help ((

Comment: I edid my code in question

Comment: @MaksIngenr your code has many problems, i will rewrite it for you, because i write in dartpad so i will comment all the code using the library and leave a comment

Comment: thank you for understanding) this is just my first acquaintance with the local repository and in general I can still say I'm learning)

Comment: @MaksIngenr check the answer update, i have to go

Comment: thank you for taking the time to do this)), but every time I restart, my tasks disappear (only the default tasks remain) and I can't delete the tasks on their right ((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244606/discussion-between-maksingenr-and-tuan).

Comment: You can look at my updated code
  in the chat?)

Comment: @MaksIngenr sure but not now, ==!